# The rock, paper scissors Javascript excercise on CodeAcademy

Tags: javascript

I'm currently going through the CodeAcademy Javascript track and although this particular excercise is letting me pass I don't feel like I'm doing it right to be honest.

In this particular excercise I need to determine what the computer's choice is between rock, paper and scissors. To do that I've declared a variable called computerChoice which is equal to Math.random(). I'm then meant to assign rock, paper or scissors to the computerChoice variable by doing if/elseif/else statements depending on the value of the random number. This was my attempt at it:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?"); 
var computerChoice = Math.random(); 
console.log(computerChoice);   - **this is from a prev. excercise to demonstrate what math.random does**

 if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
    computerChoice === "rock";
 } else if (computerChoice <= 0.66) {
     computerChoice === "paper";
 } else {
     computerChoice === "scissors";
 }
```

When I run the script in Firebug it just returns the number plus the false boolean instead of one of the choices which leads me to assume I'm doing it wrong some how. I'd appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 5):

You're using `===` instead of just `=` in your attempts to reassign the variable "computerChoice".

```
if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
}
```

The `=` operator is for (re)assigning a value; the `==` and `===` operators are for comparisons.

Comment: That's a change. I'm accustomed to seeing the reverse mistake.

Comment: I would say that `=` is for assigning a value (not changing)... e.g. a previous value may not have been set.

Comment: @scunliffe I was trying to use simple terminology, but you're right of course.